# How to create a CMD command ifor my C# windows application?

Tags: c#, cmd, command

I Want to Create a CMD command for my C3 form application
I want my app tp run normal when double clicking on it's icon
but do some specitic job by running a comman0d in c0m0d
forexample the app clear datbase by running

```
C:\myapp.exe /cleardata
```

command in CMD.

Comment: I recommend to read the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). It describes that ``\`` is the directory separator on Windows and `/` is usually used on Windows for options. It describes also that file I/O functions in the Windows API convert `/` to ``\`` as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the ``\\?\`` prefix making it possible to use `/` in file/folder paths. But it is nevertheless not good to use `/` in file/folder paths.

Comment: Note: The Microsoft documentation page has at bottom left edge an earth icon. Clicking on it lets you select a different language than English (United States) for reading the documentation page. But it is not guaranteed that the currently viewed page is available in the language selected. See also the Microsoft documentation page [Main() and command-line arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) which is available in various languages.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that not everyone here speaks perfect english and some people have trouble expressing their problem.

I am guessing you want to call your app from cmd and passing parameter to it.

You can read passed args in your main method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you call your app like C:\myapp.exe cleardata args[0] will have value cleardata.You can then process it to determine app logic.For example: if(args[0]=="cleardata"){ ClearDatabaseRecords() }else{ run your form regularly ...}